# Create dataset API(/api/v1/dataset/) giving error '400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.' when i am trying using postman

Tags: apache-superset

Create dataset API(/api/v1/dataset/) giving error '400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.' when i am trying using postman but it is working fine when i create the same from superset UI.Can anyone suggest the solution for this issue.

http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/v1/dataset/

request:
{
"database": 3,
"schema": "nrpexamqa",
"table_name": "qti_test"
}
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: You need to login before using API from Postman. Check `/api/v1/security/login` api.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the Bearer Token as shown below:

[Bearer Token Request] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYV4V.png

Given the Bearer Token it should be used in the following request, in order to get the csrf_token, with :

[CSRF Token Request]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxla5.png

Comment: In the latest version (2.x) you also need to send the `session` cookie along with the request.

Comment: @rags how can I get the session cookie?

Comment: You store it from the response and use it for subsequent requests. This shows the relevant changes: https://github.com/raags/dbt-superset/commit/a06ac905672a0eb0280c3dd866bcff106dceefac